# Jquery select option, using data attribute in Simplecart-js

Tags: jquery, simplecart

I am trying to get simplecart to set a price for each size image selected in a select box. I have select boxes for each image to sell set up as so:

```
<img class="item_image" src='my.jpg' height='50' width='50' alt="Mine"/>
<span class="item_name">My image</span>

<select class="item_size" >
<option value="5 x 7" data-price="5.00">5 x 7 - <span>$ 5.00</span></option>
<option value="8 x 10" data-price="10.00">8 x 10 - <span >$ 10.00</span></option>
<option value="16 x 20" data-price="20.00">16 x 20 - <span>$ 20.00</span</option>
</select>
<input type="text" class="item_quantity"  title="Item Quantity" value="1"/>
```

I am attempting to set the price with the data-price attribute when the select option value is selected for each item :

```
 simpleCart.bind( 'beforeAdd' , function( item ){

$('select').each(function(){ 
  var selected = $(this).find('option:selected');
    var extra = selected.data('price'); 
     item.price(extra);
  });
  });
```

I'm a noob so i am not quite getting it to work. I can get the first image prices to get set but not in other select boxes. I could use a separate ID for each select box but unsure how to do that as well. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You could have a separate `item_price` field that is updated when the select box is changed.

```
<img class="item_image" src='my.jpg' height='50' width='50' alt="Mine"/>
<span class="item_name">My image</span>

<select class="item_size">
<option value="5 x 7" data-price="5.00">5 x 7 - <span>$ 5.00</span></option>
<option value="8 x 10" data-price="10.00">8 x 10 - <span >$ 10.00</span></option>
<option value="16 x 20" data-price="20.00">16 x 20 - <span>$ 20.00</span</option>
</select>
<!-- new input --><input type="text" class="item_price" value="5.00"/>
<input type="text" class="item_quantity"  title="Item Quantity" value="1"/>
```

And then, you could do this in the JS

```
$('.item_size').on('change', function(){

    var $this = $(this),
        selected = $this.find(':selected').data('price')

    $this.siblings('.item_price').val(selected);

});
```

Working example on http://jsfiddle.net/Kvkh5/

Don't forget to change that new field to a 'hidden' field, I've made it a text field for demonstration purposes only.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this (shown on Simplecart website) :

```
simpleCart.bind( 'beforeAdd' , function( item )
{
    if( item.get( 'size' ) == '15 x 10 cm' )
    {
        item.price( '2' );
    }
    else if( item.get( 'size' ) == '15 x 21 cm' )
    {
        item.price( '3' );
    }
    else if( item.get( 'size' ) == '21 x 29,7 cm' )
    {
        item.price( '5' );
    }
    else if( item.get( 'size' ) == '21 x 29,7 cm encadré' )
    {
        item.price( '20' );
    }
});
```

But it doesn't works on ie 8. If someone know why ?

Comment: The problem with this and why i need to do it differently is that not every item.price() is the same for each size. As an example, a 15 x 10 cm size for one item might have a price of 2 but another item it might be 4. It needs to be set with the data-price for each option value.